Is there a way to reestablish SQL Server connection with R Shiny app?
My Shiny app keeps getting disconnected from the server.
This is the error I keep getting on the Posit logs:

Warning: Error in eval: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:4616: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure

My app works just fine locally. I really don't think this is caused by code in my app, but if it is, then what kind of coding mistake would cause this?
Also to give full context whenever I update my app in Posit Connect it actually works for about an hour and then crashes. As a temporary solution I keep adding in comments in my code and pushing to GitLab as an excuse to update the app.

It sounds like an intermittent network connection - are you trying to connect from the cloud back to an on-premise SQL Server? What specific version of ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server are you using? 17.2 and later have the ConnectRetryCount and ConnectRetryInterval connection properties available for use which may help. If you upgrade to 18.1 or later you might also be able to use RetryExec.

Why not just create a new connection when you need to use db operations? Sounds like you keep the original one going, and that might not stick around forever, depending on the network

@AlwaysLearning thank you. I am using version 17.1. I am reading that link and will hopefully figure out something. The server is not on-premise.

@siggemannen I'm not sure how to answer that.

Here is my way used for many years in my projects to reestablish SQL Server global connection with R Shiny app.

library(shiny)
...
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

database_encoding =  "latin1"  

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    react <- reactiveValues(
       my_connection_db1= 0
    )

  connection_react <-   function () {
    
    # react$my_connection_db1 is set at the beginning to 0 instead of NULL, 
    # for next connections, to know if there was an initial connection

    if (!is.null(react$my_connection_db1)) {
      
      
      tryCatch(
        {
          DBI::dbGetInfo(react$my_connection_db1)
        },
        error=function(e) {    
          print("Lost of connection my_connection_db1, try to reconnect (Error)")
          react$my_connection_db1<- tryCatch(
                                       DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                                        .connection_string=my_connection_db1_odbc_string, 
                                         encoding = database_encoding
                                       )
                                       , error=function(e) { NULL}
                                    )
        },
        warning=function(w) {  
         print("Lost of my_connection_db1 (Warning)")
        }
      )
      
    }
    return(react$my_connection_db1)
  }
...
}

Used everywhere in reactive components
Mydata <- reactive({
  DBI::dbGetQuery(
    connection_react(), 
    iconv(
      paste0("SELECT * FROM TOTO ... WHERE ..."
             "
      ),"UTF-8","latin1"
    )
  )
})

My initial need was for switch between 2 database (archive, actual) with a similar implementation but with 2 connections.

I'm using a similar code snippet as @phili_b to ensure I'm always using a valid Postgres connection.
Note that for the Postgres driver, DBI::dbGetInfo always returns data even if the connection is closed by the server.
A workaround is to use a function that effectively requests data from the server. DBI::dbListTables is a good candidate as the result does not need to be fetched.
# Initialize first database connection
database_keepalive <- reactiveValues(
    link = tryCatch(
               dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                         "postgres",
                         "localhost",
                         5432,
                         "postgres",
                         ""),
               error=function(e){
                    print("Error connecting to the database. Are you sure your Postgres database is running ? That your credentials are correct ?")
                    print("Full Stack Trace")
                    print(e)
                    NULL
               }
          )
)

# Function to call to ensure to always receive a valid database connection
session_db <- function() {
    tryCatch({
        DBI::dbListTables(database_keepalive$link)
     },
     error=function(e) {
          print("Lost of connection database link, reconnecting...")
          database_keepalive$link <- tryCatch(
               dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                         "postgres",
                         "localhost",
                         5432,
                         "postgres",
                         ""),
               error=function(e){
                    print("Error connecting to the database. Are you sure your Postgres database is running ? That your credentials are correct ?")
                    print("Full Stack Trace")
                    print(e)
                    NULL
               }
          )
        
    })
    return(database_keepalive$link)
}

# PostgreSQL Connection with keep alive usage
dbSendQuery(session_db(), sql("SELECT 1")


